# How can I optimise this COUNT DISTINCT on joined InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, innodb

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r.id)
FROM views v
INNER JOIN emails e ON v.email_id = e.id
INNER JOIN recipients r ON e.recipient_id = r.id
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON e.campaign_id = c.id
WHERE c.centre_id IS NULL;
```

... or, "how many unique email opens have we had? (on general campaigns)"

Currently takes about a minute and a half to run on an Amazon RDS instance. Total rows for the tables involved are roughly:

- campaigns: 250
- recipients: 330,000
- views: 530,000
- emails: 1,380,000

EXPLAIN gives me:

```
1   SIMPLE  r   index   PRIMARY UNIQ_146632C4E7927C74   767 NULL    329196  Using index
1   SIMPLE  e   ref PRIMARY,IDX_4C81E852E92F8F78,IDX_4C81E852F639F774   IDX_4C81E852E92F8F78    111 ecomms.r.id 1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  v   ref IDX_11F09C87A832C1C9    IDX_11F09C87A832C1C9    111 ecomms.e.id 1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_E3737470463CD7C3    PRIMARY 110 ecomms.e.campaign_id    1   Using where
```

What can I do to get this total faster?

Comment: I don't understand how r.id represents an opened email, nor why you need `DISTINCT`. Consider adding some sample data to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Sorry, the wording of my question wasn't clear: "unique email opens" isn't a count of opened emails, it's a count of unique recipients who have opened emails. Thus, the query needs to count recipient IDs - although, as John Bollinger points out below, I can save myself  a join by counting _emails.recipient_id_. I need the `DISTINCT` because a recipient may open an email multiple times, which I want to discount.

Comment: When do recipient records get created? I figured you knew what you were doing with the INNER JOINs. If you count on the email.recipient_id instead, you may records that don't have a matching recipients record. You should generally provide sample data and desired output with these kinds of questions, otherwise, we have to assume you know what you're doing with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join `recipients` *only* if you are not enforcing a foreign key constraint between `recipients.id` and `emails.recipent_id`, *and* you want to exclude recipients who are not (any longer) enlisted in the `recipients` table.  Otherwise, omit that table from the join straight away; you can use `emails.recipient_id` instead of `recipients.id`.  Omitting that join should be a big win.

Alternatively, omit `recipients` from the join on the basis that it is not relevant to the question posed, which is about unique *emails* opened, not about unique *recipients* to open any email.  In that case you should be able to just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` because each `emails` row is already unique.

Other than that, it looks like you're already getting good use of your indexes, though I confess I find the `EXPLAIN PLAN` output difficult to read, especially without headings.  Still, it looks like your query doesn't read the base tables at all, so it's unlikely that adding new indexes would help.

You could try executing an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on the tables involved in your query, though that probably sounds more hopeful than it should.

You should periodically run `ANALYZE TABLE` on the tables involved in this query, to give the query optimizer has the greatest likelihood of choosing the best possible plan.  It looks like the optimizer is already choosing a reasonable plan, though, so this may not help much.

If you still need better performance then there are [other possibilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization.html) (including moving to faster hardware), but they are too numerous to discuss here.

Answer (score 0):

You want MySQL to be able to utilize the `WHERE` clause to limit the result set immediately. In order to do that, you need the proper indexes to join from campaigns to emails, then from emails to recipients and views.

Put an index on campaigns.centre_id to aid the search (satisfy the `WHERE` clause). I'm assuming campaigns.id is the primary key on that table.

Put an index on emails.campaign_id to aid the join to emails from campaigns. Add recipient_id and email_id to that index to provide a covering index.

Now, the `EXPLAIN` result should show the tables in order, starting from campaigns, then emails, then the other two. MySQL will still need an internal temporary table to apply the `DISTINCT`. Are you sure you need that?
I'm assuming emails.id and recipients.id are the primary keys.